# Making PRFs out of PRGs

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function

Is it possible that we take a $PRG$ $G(k)$ of stretch $n\cdot2^n$, and read its
output as the table of a $PRF$ $F(K)$ with input and output size of $n$?

Intuitively it sounds possible however I read it somewhere that this may not be done.

Comment: Do you mean $\: n\cdot 2^{\hspace{.02 in}n} \;$? $\;\;\;$ (Instead of $\: n.2^n \;$.) $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the typo

Comment: Still no comments :) ?